# array_agg group by multiple columns where one column can contain nulls

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I'm using Postgresql 11.

**Current state**

I have a table `X` that looks like this:

```
A    B   C
____________
PR1  L1  PL1
PR1  L1  PL2
PR1  L1  PL1
PR2  L2  PL3
PR2  L2  PL4
```

I want to get an array of distinct column C values, grouped by column A and then column B.  And I'm able to use

```
SELECT A, B, ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT C) 
FROM X
GROUP BY A, B
```

This gives me my desired result:

```
PR1, L1, {PL1, PL2}
PR2, L2, {PL3, PL4}
```

**New requirement**

I now have the possibility of null values for column B.  So my data might look like:

```
A    B   C
____________
PR1  L1  PL1
PR1  L1  PL2
PR1      PL1
PR1      PL3
```

As before, I need to get an array of distinct column C values, grouped by column A and then column B.
*However*, I need to handle NULL column B values as below:

```
PR1, L1, {PL1, PL2}
PR1,   , {PL3}
```

Note the desired handling of rows 3 and 4 of table `X` where column B is null:

1. for a given column A value (PR1), if a column C value (PL1) exists for a non-null column B value (row 1) as well as a null column B value (row 3) then in the result set it should only be included in the array for the `PR1, L1` combination .
2. for a given column A value (PR1), if a column C value (PL3) exists for a null column B (row 3) but no corresponding non-null column B value, then in the result set it should be included in the array for the `PR1, null` combination.

Answer (score 0):

I'd preprocess Column B to change the values to empty strings first. Then I think your original code will work. Then you can filter out by the rules you described in your notes.

```
With temp as (
SELECT A, COALESCE(B, ''), ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT C) 
FROM X
GROUP BY A, COALESCE(B , '')
)

Select *
From temp
Where only get rows that fit your criteria
```

Comment: @A Simple Programmer thanks for response.  Your suggestion still leaves me with the same problem I have with my original query, which is that the PL1 value shows up twice in the result; once where B = L1 and once where B is null.  See desired result in my question, where PL1 is only available in the array with the L1 value. Contrast with result from your suggested query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9c44e/6/0